# Can i remove linux-image-3.2.0-4-686-pae?

Tags: debian, apt

I can see `linux-image-3.2.0-4-686-pae` as installed package:

```
# apt-cache policy linux-image-3.2.0-4-686-pae
linux-image-3.2.0-4-686-pae:
  Installé : 3.2.82-1
  Candidat : 3.2.82-1
 Table de version :
 *** 3.2.82-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

But my running kernel is:

```
uname -a
Linux igname 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) i686 GNU/Linux
```

Can i remove `linux-image-3.2.0-4-686-pae` package ? If yes, why it is still installed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost certainly installed because you upgraded this box from Debian Wheezy to Jessie (unless you're using something else that uses the exact same kernels). The dist-upgrade process won't remove your old kernel until you do it manually or until it has been replaced several times (typically 3 to 5 depending on apt configuration).

If the above is true, this is many versions old and you can uninstall it.

Comment: "you upgraded this box from Debian Wheezy to Jessie" you exactly got it. Thank's.